# QApplication.clipboard().dataChanged not work in background

Tags: python, pyqt, clipboard

I am trying to write a  dictionary program that can auto search the word when I copy some words into the clipboard.
I need the program to detect the clipboard change and search in the background.(menubar app)
but my program only updates when I click it.
(for example no use in Mac OS fullscreen mode)
is there any way to lettuce program work even when it is in the background?

mac os catalina , PYQT5

I use QApplication.clipboard().dataChanged.connect() to detect the clipboard change

```py
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        QApplication.clipboard().dataChanged.connect(self.clipboardChange)

    def clipboardChange(self):
        print(QApplication.clipboard().text())
        self.raise_()
```

in main file:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    icon = QIcon("dic.png")
    tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
    tray.setIcon(icon)
    tray.setVisible(True)
    #menu = QMenu()
    action = QAction("A menu item")
    #menu.addAction(action)
    #tray.setContextMenu(menu)

    myWin = MyMainWindow()
    myWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the program only update when I click it

Comment: Qt only receives OS events if the GUI is visible, if it is not, then it will not be notified. If you want to detect OS events when the application is not visible you must use the OS libraries.

Comment: @eyllanesc It should be noted that "background" OS event detection depends on both systems and features. In this specific case, it's true for the clipboard on MacOS, while notabily on Linux and Windows it works even if the application is not the active one.